# Search a many to many relationship with a wild card, performance issues

Tags: mysql, sql, scalability

I am building a database for an app and I am testing performance issues on a *larger* data set.  I generated about 250,000 location records.  Each location can be assigned to many categories and a category can be assigned to many locations.  My data-set has 2-4 categories assigned to each location.

I want to allow the user to search for locations by filtering which categories should be allowed using a wild card search.  So maybe I want to match all categories with the word "red" in it.  So if I type red, now it shows all locations which have a category title that has "red" in it. In addition, I would like to wildcard search the location title with that same string.

I wrote up a query which *works* but performance is awful in large data-sets.  Essentially I am using inner queries which is fine if my limit is set and I find results quick (around .05ms).  If I don't find any results right away, it looks like it goes through the whole database and the query takes around 9-10 seconds.

Here is a simplified layout of my database:

```
locations: id | title | address
categories: id | title
locations_categories: id | location_id | category_id
```

Here is the query I currently am using:

```
SELECT `id`,`title`,`address`
FROM (`locations`)
WHERE title LIKE '%string%'
AND WHERE id IN (
 SELECT location_id 
 FROM locations_categories 
 JOIN categories ON categories.id = locations_categories.category_id 
 WHERE categories.title LIKE '%string%')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you main query just uses the value of the subquery, so it can be rewritten:

```
 SELECT location_id 
 FROM locations_categories 
 JOIN categories ON categories.id = locations_categories.category_id 
 WHERE categories.title LIKE '%string%'
```

But I'd propose to split this query in two—JOINs are slow for big datasets.  First one will get necessary category IDs (with paging):

```
SELECT id
FROM categories
WHERE title LIKE '%string%' LIMIT BY <start>, <step>
```

Then you can get locations_categories:

```
SELECT location_id FROM locations_categories WHERE category_id IN (...)
```

And you'll use the location IDs you've got to retrieve corresponding records:

```
SELECT * FROM locations WHERE id IN (...)
```

These 3 queries combined will be much faster then your original one.

Also, make sure your title column is indexed—it can be the bottleneck.  But since you have a wildcard at the start of the search term, you'll have to use [`FULLTEXT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-search.html) index here.

Comment: I like the approach in your second solution.  I should mention that your first solution probably wouldn't work since my SELECT on location will actually include more then ID since I may also be adding WHERE filters on the location part.  I have updated my question to reflect.

Answer (score 1):

Your explain plan will confirm (or disprove) this but I suspect that your issue is that the leading % in the clauses

```
WHERE categories.title LIKE '%string%'
```

and

```
WHERE title LIKE '%string%`
```

forces full table scans.   To address this often requires some knowledge of the domain and application in question

The simple approach is to only search for 'starts with'.  Others include full text searching, function based indexes, having a 'grouping table' that presorts and lists the relevant records for known searches.